# Upload photos from Database to clientside

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend

I have a react front end project that i’d like to include some photos, but i’ll be frequently adding and deleting photos, so what i’d like to do is create a model and upload the pictures from the database to appear in the clientside. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: For file upload you need the some backend, like node.js. Then you store the file to a specific location and file location path to the DB in some table. You call a node API to get the image path and put it into you `img` tag.

Comment: if you want to delete and upload from front end react side then use filepond package. see the docs https://github.com/pqina/filepond